# Spring Boot 1.5.x with Spring Data Elasticsearch 2.1.x how to secure Elasticsearch 2.4.4

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.4

How to secure access to Elasticsearch 2.4.x when in application is used Spring Boot 1.5.x  with Spring Data Elasticsearch 2.1.x

Comment: These versions are long outdated and out of support. I doubt that someone still has this running

Comment: I know but maybe someone remember something. Unfortunely update to new versions are impasible.